# How to extract text from child Text Nodes - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

From the code below I would like to extract: "I give you €0.00.".

With the following xpath I can target it from Developer tools:

> //*[@id="windowID"]/text()[2]

But using Selenium I can only look for this element with `driver.findElement(By.Xpath(""))`

The problem is that it says that the result of xpath expression is not an element, but an [object Text]

If I target only the ancestor div (windowID), then the whole text is received. I only want the mentioned part to be saved to a string.

```
<div id="windowID" class="windowClass">"Your are awesome."<br>"I give you €0.00."<br>"But you should give me €0.00."<br>"Would you like to do that?"</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text  **I give you €0.00.** you can use the following line of code :

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='windowClass' and @id='windowID']"));
string text = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;", elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I get all the text and split the text by `<br>` and we can print the text by separating.

```
 String mytext=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='windowID'].getAttribute("innerHTML");
    String[] separatestring= mytext.split(Pattern.quote("<br>"));
    String firstone= separatestring[0];
    String secondtone= separatestring[1];
    System.out.println(firstone);
    System.out.println(secondtone);
```

I did it by java, Here you can convert it to C#. Hope it will help you.