# How do I write xpath to extract a date from a text node using Selenium and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<dd>
::before
<strong>Test Date:</strong>
"
7/6/20 - Monday"
::after
</dd>
```

the above is the sample html.

I want to locate the date which is after "Test Date:"
Since there will be many dates in the page, I want to locate the date with reference to the text "Test Date:"
How do I write xpath for this requirement?
or using any other locator.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to write xpath (which in your case would be `//dd/strong[text()='Test Date:']/following-sibling::text()[1]`). You need a separate text node which cannot be treated by Selenium as a web element. Use `IJavaScriptExecutor`:

```cs
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string dateText = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.evaluate(\"//dd/strong[text()='Test Date:']/following-sibling::text()[1]\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.cloneNode(true).text;");
```

Answer (score 0):

The text **7/6/20 - Monday** is within a text node of the parent `<dd>` node. So to extract the date which is just after **Test Date:** you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//dd[./strong[text()='Test Date:']]"));
string text = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;", element);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to extract text from child Text Nodes - Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040526/how-to-extract-text-from-child-text-nodes-selenium/50040924#50040924)
- [How to get parent element text and remove child element text selenium c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589794/how-to-get-parent-element-text-and-remove-child-element-text-selenium-c/50591292#50591292)